# contentInset not working with UISearchDisplayController tableView?

Tags: ios, scroll, hide, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Using `UISearchDisplayController`, I am showing a `UIView` in bottom so causes hiding the filtered data while scrolling the table. I used `contentInset` property to show data in bottom.

My problem is that `NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.contentInset)` is showing the `bottom` value as `216` even if I reset the UIEdgeInsetsZero.

When I do multiple search the more data is not visible after scrolling:

[image]

Comment: I am not getting your question please explain briefly.

Comment: Can you show some more code and maybe a screenshot of what you have and what you want?

Comment: I have a tableView list, on tap of the row i am showing a view from bottom and doing some operation.When i click the second last row the bottom view  which appear that hide the last row.So I wanted to make the contentInset till from that View edge so that data can be visible.Do that i am contentInset bottom value as 50.so on search  first time when i am getting filtered data I am able to fine.If I again search then my table data is goes beyond the table and i am not able to pull that data by scrolling.This is my issue.Please let me know did you get this or not?

Comment: I have solved this problem , UISearchDisplaycontroller handle automatic due to keyboard and 216 is about that.now i have set the contentInset proper , and working fine .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to set self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.contentInset, you should do in the delegate:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    controller.searchResultsTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.f, 30.f, 0.f);
}
```